# How many integers between $1$ and $1000$ are divisible by $2, 4,$ or $7?$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, inclusion-exclusion

How many integers between 1 and 1000 are divisible by $2, 4,$ or $7?$

$A \cup B = A+B- A \cap B=500+142-71=571$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that any number divisible by $4$ is divisible by $2$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: Your answer is indeed correct, is there any other purpose on this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Alternative solution:**

Denote $A_n$ as the set of integers between $1$ and $1000$ divisible by $n$. Then you can blindly follow the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement)

$$|A_2 \cup A_4 \cup A_7| \\= |A_2|+|A_4| + |A_7| - |A_2 \cap A_4| - |A_4 \cap A_7| - |A_7 \cap A_2| + |A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_7| \tag 1$$

Note that $A_2 \cap A_4 = A_4, A_4 \cap A_7 = A_{28}, A_7 \cap A_2 = A_{14}, A_2 \cap A_4 \cap A_7 = A_4 \cap A_7 = A_{28}$ so some of the terms in $(1)$ will cancel out and you don't need to calculate all of them.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find out how many numbers are divisible by $2$ and how many numbers are divisible by $7$. Note that $2 | 4$ and numbers are divisible by both $2$ and $7$ iff they're divisible by $14$ (why?). Find out which numbers are counted in both f the lists of multiples.

Answer (score -1):

> Not a 'real' answer, but it was too big for a comment. I think that you're looking for a solution without using a calculator or PC but maybe this gives some insight. I did only a quick search with the following bound: $1\le\text{n}\le10^3$.

I wrote and ran some [Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram_Mathematica)-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^3;
ParallelTable[
  If[TrueQ[IntegerQ[n/2] || IntegerQ[n/4] || IntegerQ[n/7]], n, 
   Nothing], {n, 1, \[Alpha]}] //. {} -> Nothing
```

Running the code gives:

```
Out[1]={2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 
34, 35, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 
63, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 77, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 91, 
92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 104, 105, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 
118, 119, 120, 122, 124, 126, 128, 130, 132, 133, 134, 136, 138, 140, 
142, 144, 146, 147, 148, 150, 152, 154, 156, 158, 160, 161, 162, 164, 
166, 168, 170, 172, 174, 175, 176, 178, 180, 182, 184, 186, 188, 189,
190, 192, 194, 196, 198, 200, 202, 203, 204, 206, 208, 210, 212, 214, 
216, 217, 218, 220, 222, 224, 226, 228, 230, 231, 232, 234, 236, 238, 
240, 242, 244, 245, 246, 248, 250, 252, 254, 256, 258, 259, 260, 262, 
264, 266, 268, 270, 272, 273, 274, 276, 278, 280, 282, 284, 286, 287, 
288, 290, 292, 294, 296, 298, 300, 301, 302, 304, 306, 308, 310, 312, 
314, 315, 316, 318, 320, 322, 324, 326, 328, 329, 330, 332, 334, 336, 
338, 340, 342, 343, 344, 346, 348, 350, 352, 354, 356, 357, 358, 360,
362, 364, 366, 368, 370, 371, 372, 374, 376, 378, 380, 382, 384, 385, 
386, 388, 390, 392, 394, 396, 398, 399, 400, 402, 404, 406, 408, 410, 
412, 413, 414, 416, 418, 420, 422, 424, 426, 427, 428, 430, 432, 434, 
436, 438, 440, 441, 442, 444, 446, 448, 450, 452, 454, 455, 456, 458, 
460, 462, 464, 466, 468, 469, 470, 472, 474, 476, 478, 480, 482, 483, 
484, 486, 488, 490, 492, 494, 496, 497, 498, 500, 502, 504, 506, 508, 
510, 511, 512, 514, 516, 518, 520, 522, 524, 525, 526, 528, 530, 532, 
534, 536, 538, 539, 540, 542, 544, 546, 548, 550, 552, 553, 554, 556, 
558, 560, 562, 564, 566, 567, 568, 570, 572, 574, 576, 578, 580, 581, 
582, 584, 586, 588, 590, 592, 594, 595, 596, 598, 600, 602, 604, 606, 
608, 609, 610, 612, 614, 616, 618, 620, 622, 623, 624, 626, 628, 630, 
632, 634, 636, 637, 638, 640, 642, 644, 646, 648, 650, 651, 652, 654, 
656, 658, 660, 662, 664, 665, 666, 668, 670, 672, 674, 676, 678, 679, 
680, 682, 684, 686, 688, 690, 692, 693, 694, 696, 698, 700, 702, 704, 
706, 707, 708, 710, 712, 714, 716, 718, 720, 721, 722, 724, 726, 728, 
730, 732, 734, 735, 736, 738, 740, 742, 744, 746, 748, 749, 750, 752, 
754, 756, 758, 760, 762, 763, 764, 766, 768, 770, 772, 774, 776, 777, 
778, 780, 782, 784, 786, 788, 790, 791, 792, 794, 796, 798, 800, 802, 
804, 805, 806, 808, 810, 812, 814, 816, 818, 819, 820, 822, 824, 826, 
828, 830, 832, 833, 834, 836, 838, 840, 842, 844, 846, 847, 848, 850, 
852, 854, 856, 858, 860, 861, 862, 864, 866, 868, 870, 872, 874, 875, 
876, 878, 880, 882, 884, 886, 888, 889, 890, 892, 894, 896, 898, 900, 
902, 903, 904, 906, 908, 910, 912, 914, 916, 917, 918, 920, 922, 924, 
926, 928, 930, 931, 932, 934, 936, 938, 940, 942, 944, 945, 946, 948, 
950, 952, 954, 956, 958, 959, 960, 962, 964, 966, 968, 970, 972, 973, 
974, 976, 978, 980, 982, 984, 986, 987, 988, 990, 992, 994, 996, 998, 
1000}
```

So, there are $571$ solutions. I found that, using the following code:

```
In[2]:=Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 10^3;
Length[ParallelTable[
   If[TrueQ[IntegerQ[n/2] || IntegerQ[n/4] || IntegerQ[n/7]], n, 
    Nothing], {n, 1, \[Alpha]}] //. {} -> Nothing]

Out[2]=571
```

Extending the bound to $1\le\text{n}\le10^9$ gives $571428571$ solutions.